# Recent infrastructure issue

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I have encountered a problem. I recently rebooted my instance, it turned out that after the reboot I lost access to the SSH command. After typing the command, I get a Connection timed out error. The next day going to the Cloud site I got this message (image). Is there anything I can do about it?

image

[image: 1]

to work normally so I can connect using SSH

Comment: you could stop the instance and detach the boot volume then attach the boot volume to a fresh instance as a data volume, then look at the logs to debug see https://docs.public.oneportal.content.oci.oraclecloud.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Block/Tasks/detachingabootvolume.htm